# Does Git commit takes a snapshot of the whole repository or just of the staging area?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

Does the command `git commit` takes a snapshot of my whole project or just of the staging area/index?

I already know that git commits are nodes of a graph, that every commit stores a pointer to the previous commit in the chain, that a branch is just a pointer to a commit and that HEAD is a pointer to the current branch.

However, I have been searching for an answer to this question on the Internet, but I seem to get different answers from different websites, and I can't get my head around this.

From [Git pro book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository):

> In order to begin tracking a new file, you use the command `git add`.
>
> Now that your staging area is set up the way you want it, you can commit your changes. Remember that anything that is still unstaged — any files you have created or modified that you haven’t run git add on since you edited them — won’t go into this commit. They will stay as modified files on your disk.

From [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

> git-commit
> Create a new commit containing the current contents of the index and the given log message describing the changes

As I can understand from those statements, it seems to me that `git commit` takes a snapshot of just the staging area.

However, looking for some answers in this sub I found:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72706370/17791373)

> In Git, all commits are immutable snapshots of your project (ignored files excluded) at a specific point in time. This means that each and every commit contains a unique representation of your entire project, not just the modified or added files (deltas), at the time of commit.
>
> Everytime a new commit is created, a snapshot of your entire project is recorded and stored to the internal database following a DAG data structure.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39611880/17791373)

> A "commit" in git is not a change (delta), but represents the entire state. But a commit contains more than just state: it also has a pointer to a parent commit (typically one, but can be any number), i.e. the previous commit in the repository's history.

After posting this question, I was able to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077295/17791373) too, that seems to give more details about the question:

> You can have a lot of changes in a lot of files and only include in a commit a few of these changes. That does not mean that those other files are not part of the commit: technically all unchanged files are part of that commit, they are just not part of the commit diff.

From those answers, it seems to me that a commit is a snapshot of the whole state of the project at a given time.

Does somebody have a good, yet simple, explanation?

Comment: Conceptually, the staging area *is* the snapshot. In practice, `git` does not actually keep separate copies of all (unchanged) files somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the staging area is the snapshot". Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I don't know if this is *exactly* how it works, but you can imagine the contents of the new commit being whatever is in the parent-to-be (since it's a snapshot as well), with the contents of the index overriding it where applicable.

Comment: That is, the new snapshot is a combination of the currently checked out commit and the contents of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion can get seemingly sloppy when everyone's so familiar with the subject they start presuming listeners understand. When listeners *do* understand, communications can get briefer and briefer as the shared assumptions start compounding.

So for instance when discussing Git commits, people very familiar with Git will understand in what contexts "your entire project" is referring only to its tracked state.

Comment: Does this mean that `git commit` takes a snapshot of just the staging area then?

Comment: The snapshot's pretty much already taken. `git add` adds the content to your repo and updates the index entry to point to it. `git commit` makes trees in the repo pointing to all the staged content and a commit pointing to the new toplevel tree, a git "tree" is unsurprisingly a near-exact analog for a filesystem directory node.

Answer (score 1):

With some minor quibbles, the index / staging-area (these are two terms for the same thing) *is* the snapshot, as [jthill said indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832187/1256452), and [chepner said directly in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832021/does-git-commit-takes-a-snapshot-of-the-whole-repository-or-just-of-the-staging/73836029#comment130370684_73832021).  The index contains—indirectly—the *full form of every file that will be* in the new commit, in the format it will have in the commit, with the following exceptions:

- The index entry for any given file includes a *stage number*.  This number must be zero, or `git write-tree`—which is the internal step that turns the index into a Git internal *tree object*—will complain and fail.

  (Nonzero stage numbers imply that you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, as a result of `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, or similar.  Your job as the programmer, in this case, is to resolve the conflicts and write the correct version of the file *to* the index as "stage zero", which you normally do using working tree files and `git add`, perhaps with the help of `git mergetool` and/or other programs.)
- Each index entry stores the *full path name of the file*, e.g., `path/to/file`.  Note that the index has this path name with *forward* slashes, even on Windows where the working tree copy is generally referred-to via `path\to\file` by the OS itself.
- The index includes the file's *mode* in a Git-ized internal format that "accidentally on purpose" more or less matches the Linux internal `st_mode` field, minus some data.
- The index includes a bunch of cache data to speed things up; this cache data is not included in the snapshot.

The format of an index entry is generally compressed and rather fancy and there are multiple index version formats (they're numbered).  See [the Git documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitformat-index.txt) for more; note that this recently moved from an internal technical documentation directory.  This isn't something normal users normally care about, but it's been officially documented so that other language libraries can work with Git index files.

Git's "tree" objects store file name components, e.g., when a file is named `path/to/file`, the path gets broken up at the slashes to form two tree objects `path` and `to`.  The `file` entry then goes in the tree object for `to`, whose hash ID goes in the tree object for `path`; the hash ID for the top level tree object goes into the commit as the commit's (required, and required-to-be-singular) `tree` entity.  That provides the commit's version of indirection, which is hierarchical, vs the index's indirection, which is flat: the index stores Git *blob* object hash IDs directly, along with full path names.

By storing the file *contents* as blob objects, Git gets instant de-duplication for duplicated file content.  This also means that Git can instantly tell whether some file in commit C1 has the same content as some file in commit C2, because if those two files have the same content, they will use the same blob hash ID.

Note that (again with some quibbles), *checking out* a commit consists of reading its top level tree into the index and your working tree.  Making a new commit consists of writing the index to a series of tree objects, ending with a single top level tree, and then writing a commit object that refers to this tree (and then updating the current branch name, if in attached-HEAD mode).  The quibbles here all have to do with uncommitted work: see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).